# glibc 2.7 on CentOS 5.5?

Tags: centos, redhat, gnu, glibc

I'm trying to run a program that requires glibc 2.7, but I'm running it on CentOS 5.5. Is there any way to do this? I can't upgrade to CentOS 6.

Comment: You're going to have to upgrade or see if the program can be compiled against the older glibc in CentOS 5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm.  glibc 2.5 is a dependency on pretty much everything in CentOS5.  If you change it to glibc 2.7, your box will explode.

Here's some discussion over in the CentOS forums:

https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=28345&forum=41

https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=27133&forum=38

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a couple times, most recently while back using Snort. Attempting to upgrade to 2.7 will.definately blow up yourto box. I rendered my test system unbootable when I tried this previously.
Your best bet is to upgrade if at all possible. Failing that many applications can be recompiled against glib 2.6. If you have to deal with a no install from source on your production infrastructure take a look at how to build RPMs. A lot of products either include a spec file or there is one publically available.

Comment: Did you have a problem with your keyboard when writing the first part?

Comment: New mobile phone. Autocorrect needs some adjustment.