# GLIBC 2.6 on Centos 5.8

Tags: centos, glibc, g-wan

There are many discussions about glibc on CentOS on serverfault but I couldn't find one directly related to these: I have CentOS 5.8 server and I would like to install G-WAN. It requires GLIBC 2.6, I have 2.5 right now.

Does CentOS 5.8 support GLIBC 2.6 or do I have to upgrade to CentOS 6? Is there a documentation about these requirements?

Thanks.

Comment: G-WAN worked hard recently to remove this issue, look at this other reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559098/which-linux-kernels-and-linux-distros-are-supported-by-g-wan/13562162#13562162

Answer (score 1):

The discussions you may have seen are correct...

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/231213/newer-glibc-for-rhel-centos-5-x), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/372243/glibc-2-7-on-centos-5-5), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/422396/what-can-go-wrong-with-a-glibc-upgrade), and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/407575/glibc-2-7-not-found).

You can't change glibc versions on CentOS 5. You'll need an upgrade to a newer version of RHEL/CentOS.

EL6 ships with glibc 2.12:

```
Name        : glibc                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.12                              Vendor: CentOS
```

Of course, upgrading [CentOS versions isn't particularly easy](https://serverfault.com/questions/449048/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-upgrade-between-major-versions-of-red-hat-and-centos)...

Comment: Foo. They just make it _sound_ hard so we can charge exorbitant consulting rates for doing it and making it look easy.